# MJML how to set compile output directory same as the found input file directory?

Tags: mjml

I am trying to compile a folder with subfolders that will each have a .mjml file. This command works: `mjml ./views/**/*.mjml.html.erb -o`, however I can't seem to set the output to be in the same directory as the initial file, all of the files from each of the subfolders will be piled up in the root directory, and if I set any directory it will pile up there obviously.

I tried using `**` and such but to no avail. I think it is possible to run a separate command for each of the subfolders but it will eat up a lot of resources and time, so it is not viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I did something wrong before, iteration through every folder is quick enough.

I just used glob to map out all of the files I need to compile and ran the mjml compiler on each one individually. It was surprisingly fast (10-50ms per file).